# Cant use rdlc that I created using visual studio 2015 in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rdlc, visual-studio-2017

I have created rdlc reports for ASP.Net MVC project using Visual studio 2015 and they worked fine. Recently I started using Visual studio 2017 and when I try to open an rdlc report in browser I get the following error:

> The definition of the report is invalid. The report definition is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. This could be the result of publishing a report definition of a later version of Reporting Services, or that the report definition contains XML that is not well-formed or the XML is not valid based on the Report Definition schema. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

Based on that error I realized that VS2017 changed my rdlc namespace from 2008 to 2016 but I don't know how to fix it to work again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by updating ReportViewer to version 14.0.0.0 and installing Microsoft.RdlcDesigner.

Comment: I cannot find **Microsoft.RdlcDesigner**

Comment: [Microsoft.RdlcDesigner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqlReportingServices.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001)  Here